# Spring JUnit Mockito unit test controller Specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, gradle

I want to write unit test for simply spring controller. 
Everything works - controller, views and model is ok, because when i deploy it on my local tomcat it does exactly what i want. But there is one problem. I try to write unit test for it (I use this tutorial: 
    http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-configuration/ ) and i get many exceptions.

I tried everything and still it doesn't work.

Here is my code: (IndexControllerTest.java)

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppContext.class})
    public class IndexControllerTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepositoryMock;

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Before
        public void setUp(){
            Mockito.reset(userRepositoryMock);

            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
        }


        @Test
        public void testName() throws Exception {


        }
    }
```

(WebAppContext.java):

```
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("pl.com.tegess.UnitTestForSpringController")
    @EnableMongoRepositories("pl.com.tegess.UnitTestForSpringController.repositories")
    public class WebAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        }

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
            configurer.enable();
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver(){

            SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

            Properties exceptionMappings = new Properties();
            exceptionMappings.put("pl.com.tegess.UnitTestForSpringConfiguration.exceptions.ControllerNotFoundException", "error/404");
            exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.Exception", "error/error");
            exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.RuntimeException", "error/error");

            exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings);
            Properties statusCodes = new Properties();
            statusCodes.put("error/404", "404");
            statusCodes.put("error/error", "500");

            exceptionResolver.setStatusCodes(statusCodes);

            return exceptionResolver;
        }

        @Bean
        @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
        public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
            ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
            templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
            templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
            return templateResolver;
        }

        @Bean

        public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
            return templateEngine;
        }

        @Bean

        public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
            ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
            return viewResolver;
        }

    }
```

And the controller code: (IndexController.java)

```
    @Controller
    public class IndexController {

        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Autowired
        public IndexController(UserRepository userRepository){
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index(Model model){
            Random random = new Random();
            Integer i = random.nextInt();
            this.userRepository.insertUser(new Member(i.toString()));
            model.addAttribute("text", "SomeText");
            return "index";
        }

    }
```

And the most important thing: (my gradle build.gradle)

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'war'

    jar {
        baseName = 'UnitTestForSpringController'
        version = '1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE")
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE'
        compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.3.RELEASE")
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.6.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mail:4.0.3.RELEASE'
        compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
        compile("org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5")
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
        compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'
        providedCompile("javax:javaee-web-api:6.0")
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '1.11'
    }
```

And here i paste the log:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\bin" -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\lib\util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\Szymek\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath2137920508870965803.tmp com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 pl.com.tegess.UnitTestForSpringController.controllers.IndexControllerTest,testName
    [main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@79698539: startup date [Sat Aug 16 00:40:36 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@57a3af25] to prepare test instance [pl.com.tegess.UnitTestForSpringController.controllers.IndexControllerTest@2b662a77]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testContext': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.test.context.TestContext]: Specified class is an interface
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.test.context.TestContext]: Specified class is an interface
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
        ... 49 more

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testContext': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.test.context.TestContext]: Specified class is an interface
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.test.context.TestContext]: Specified class is an interface
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
        ... 49 more
    Process finished with exit code -1
```

I found that the reason could be that i have providedCompile javaee in my build.gradle and when i run the test it is not available, but i don't know how can i fix it. Thank for any help :)

After i changed this TextContext to right, i still have similar exceptions:

`[main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@3cda1055: startup date [Thu Sep 04 11:10:08 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'messageSource': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=testContext; factoryMethodName=messageSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class pl.com.tegess.UnitTestForSpringController.configuration.TestContext] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appContext; factoryMethodName=messageSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [pl/com/tegess/UnitTestForSpringController/configuration/AppContext.class]]
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@9cb8225] to prepare test instance [pl.com.tegess.UnitTestForSpringController.controllers.IndexControllerTest@76b07f29]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 50 more`

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that you have imported the *org.springframework.test.context.TestContext* interface. My tutorial uses *TestContext* class (I should have named it a bit better to avoid this).

The source code of the *TestContext* class looks as follows:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;

@Configuration
public class TestContext {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TodoService todoService() {
        return Mockito.mock(TodoService.class);
    }
}
```

Just add this class to your project and import it instead of the *TestContext* interface. You might want to rename it thought to avoid this from happening again.

Also, you might want to consider using the standalone configuration because this way you don’t have to configure the required mock objects as beans. The application context based setup becomes painful when you have a lot of mock objects because you have to remember to configure them in your application context configuration class.

If you use standalone configuration, you don’t have to worry about this because you can configure the required mock objects in the test class.

Comment: Hi, i make it now and it doesn't work still. I paste exceptions in post above.

Answer (score 1):

Following [@pkainulainen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313554/pkainulainen) suggestion and also [this post](http://www.jayway.com/2012/09/08/spring-controller-tests-2-0/), this should fix your issue:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppContext.class})
public class IndexControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepositoryMock;

    @Autowired
    private IndexController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        Mockito.reset(userRepositoryMock);
        controller = new IndexController(userRepositoryMock);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

You can find more information about `standaloneSetup` [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-setup-options)

Answer (score 0):

I answered something like this some time ago.

Pls have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25840799/1880376

It might help you :)